Is it safe to destructively iterate over a dictionary in Julia?
Is it safe to destructively iterate over a dictionary in Julia?
Here is an example
d = Dict()

for key in keys(d)
    pop!(d, key)
end

What matters is whether keys(d) returns an iterator or a collection. (I think.)
julia> typeof(keys(d))
Base.KeySet{String, Dict{String, Int64}}

According to this documentation page, it looks like keys() returns an iterator, and therefore presumably KeySet is an iterator?
Does that imply iterating over a dictionary in this way is not a safe operation?
Popping an element from a dictionary is usually an operation which you might expect will invalidate an iterator.

Because the usual Julia Dict implements keys via an underlying second hash-map of Dict key to actual hash-key, which the keys function iterates as an iterator encapsulating an iterator, your code is safe.
Note however that if you add an item within your for loop, it is undefined whether the iteration will iterate the new item or not, as that is possibly based on the underlying hash value.

Thanks for this, can you draw a simple diagram in text showing how it works? I'm guessing the add function may cause the hash values to change, because it might create a hash collision or otherwise cause the hash values to be recalculated?

It's pretty complicated for a diagram here. the relevant code is in this file: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/dict.jl and you can see at line 712 a call to skip_deleted, which means that the iterator implementation skips entries in the underlying hash table that have been deleted already, and only returns filled (valid) indexes into the Dict's underlying key table.
